# Stream azure communication services to azure media live stream

Tags: azure, cloud, video-streaming, azure-media-services, azure-communication-services

I am currently creating an application that streams a virtual meeting to a larger audience. I am using azure communication services video calling for the video chat. I would like to send the output of this call to a live-stream event on azure media services. What is the best way to go about doing this? Will I have to capture the video call media and stream to RTMP? Is there a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Work to support RTMP relay from Azure Communication services is currently in progress. See https://github.com/Azure/Communication/projects/1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/media-comp for additional information.